# std::initializer_list usage in variadic template function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

I can't understand how below code snippet works. Especially `std::initializer_list` usage.

```
template<typename ... T>
auto sum(T ... t)
{
   typename std::common_type<T...>::type result{};
   std::initializer_list<int>{ (result += t, 0) ... };

   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<typename ... T>
auto sum(T ... t)
{
   //getting the common type of the args in t and initialize a new var
   //called result using default constructor
   typename std::common_type<T...>::type result{};

  //(result += t, 0) ... this just sum the result and the next arg in the
  //parameter pack and then returns zero, hence the initializer_list will be filled 
  //only by zeros and at the end result will hold the sum of the args 
   std::initializer_list<int>{ (result += t, 0) ... };

   return result;
}
```

It's equivalent to

```
template<typename ... T>
auto sum(T ... t)
{
    return (t+...);
}
```

Comment: It makes me sad that we need hackery like this in C++ to quickly navigate parameter packs. How is this expressive?!

Comment: How can initializer_list perform recursively inside parenthesis ?

Comment: @MustafaCOKER It doesn't. this `(result += t, 0) ...` returns `0,0,0,..` inside the parenthesis. like if you write `{0,0,0,...}`

Comment: Hi Guys, Sorry but I cant understand the role of zero after `result += t`. And also, compiler doesnt care this parameter. If I changed it(`result += t, 2` or `result += t, false`), result remains same. And If I delete this param, result remains same again, but compiler gives warning.

Comment: @MustafaCOKER this is a temporary object `std::initializer_list<int>{ (result += t, 0) ... }`, as soon as the expression finishes, the object vanishes, hence it won't affect the result. the role of the comma operator is both expressions (on the right of it and on the left) is done and then the result of the one on the right returns, hence the end will be the result will be increased by `t` (`t` has `n` different value) and you have a temporary initializer list of `n` zeros.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very very very much.